# Where the driver for CDMA/GSM hardware?

Tags: cellular-radio, radio-firmware

i.e. I have a phone in CDMA from HTC, who provides the CDMA hardware driver (radio-firmware ?),Google Android source tree or HTC?

If the driver is provided by Google Android source tree, then I can compile a custom version of Android for my phone, If from HTC, then I don't know how can I compile an Android and drive the HTC CDMA hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio is closed source and provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: Where to get? Where to put? system.img or other?

Comment: @lovespring The manufacturers generally do not provide radio firmware for users to experiment with.  People may have extracted it from various ROMs, however, and posted it.  You should check the [XDA forum](forum.xda-developers.com) for your device, search for "modem" or "baseband".  Normally you flash it directly to the device.

Comment: @Matthew Is radio firmware just a .so and living in flash memory?

Comment: @lovespring I don't believe it's a library, no.  I just opened a modem package for my device and the file is `modem.bin` and it is written to a specific part of memory, in this case `/dev/block/bml12`.

Comment: @Matthew So, baseband is a device from the point of view of linux. Is the baseband firmware a linux driver? if not, then how to communicate to linux kernel?

Comment: I'm noy sure.  This might help: http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html